# Typescript assert-like type guard

Tags: typescript

Is this possible to have types restricted without `if` by function calls that `never` return for e.g `undefined` like `assert` in Typescript?

Example code:

```
interface Foo { bar(): void }
function getFoo(): Foo | undefined { }

function test() {
    const foo = someService.getFoo();
    assert(foo);
    if (!foo) { // now mandatory because without this foo may be still undefined even if assert protects us from this
        return;
    }
    foo.bar(); // , here foo may be undefined
}
```

I would like to be able to write `assert` in such way that i can skip following `if (!foo)` clause and have `foo` type restricted to plain `Foo`.

Is this possible in Typescript?

I've tried adding overloads with `never` for types that throw:

```
function assertGuard(v: undefined | null | '' | 0 | false): never;
function assertGuard(v: any): void; // i'm not sure which one is  captured by TS typesystem here

function assertGuard<T>(v: T | undefined) {
    if (v === undefined || v === null || v === '' || v === 0 || v === false) {
         throw new AssertionError({message: 'foo'})
    }
}
```

This one compiles, but call to `assertGuard(foo)` doesn't recognize that for `undefined` it will return `never` so doesn't restrict `foo` to `Foo`.

I've found possible workarounds but i consider classical `assert` a cleaner approach:

```
function assertResultDefined<T>(v: T|undefined): T | never {
    if (v === undefined) {
        throw new Error('foo');
    }
    return v;
}
function die(): never { throw new Error('value expected)}

const foo = assertResultDefined(getFoo()) // foo is Foo, undefined is erased
const foo = getFoo() || die();
    // undefined is erased from foo
    / CONS: doesn't play well with types that interpolate to `false` like 0, ''
```

Comment: Note, this question is outdated because TypeScript 3.7 introduced very special syntax for problem raised in question, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59017341/269448

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Typescript 3.7 adds [assertions in control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695).

> An `asserts` return type predicate indicates that the function returns only when the assertion holds and otherwise throws an exception

Hacks on consumer side are not needed anymore.

```
interface Foo { bar(): void }
declare function getFoo(): Foo | undefined;

function assert(value: unknown): asserts value {
    if (value === undefined) {
        throw new Error('value must be defined');
    }
}

function test() {
    const foo = getFoo();
    // foo is Foo | undefined here
    assert(foo);
    // foo narrowed to Foo
    foo.bar();
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7IEZxQAUAlAFzIBu6wAJsgL4BQtECANoSjAK4gJhg6EMgDmEMBnSkKU5AB9kfVjFARaAbiZNe-QcORwAzkehgilOOx4QKfANYh0AdxDlDJs0apWbOJsiByMAwyBa%20KAC80UogKmq0JP5BKchgABZQLsggEM7IAKJQWcQA5JbWKAC2PEZg%20CjxubSlJFopzMw6fAJCIpB1pMlBCMJ1yDCYyJFiElKk7UEA9EsTU8DecorKEKrNyOnQEAFBxqZQ5pPobSeBK2tYIIRZzuppWFK3DwB0BMQ3DCAA)

---

Additionally one can assert that provided parameter is of required type:

```
declare function assertIsArrayOfStrings(obj: unknown): asserts obj is string[];

function foo(x: unknown) {
    assertIsArrayOfStrings(x);
    return x[0].length;  // x has type string[] here
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXygGdCQYMBJQgQRhigE8B5RAZQxi1QHNCAKHAEYArAFzw0Aa1Q4A7qgCUYoiTKF4gofCxrC7TlwDaAXQDcAKDMp02PEhw5eADzGTpc+fADeZ+L4LFSCmpaBmY2Dm4+R3lzP3g4DGQYfEcDAAYjADoIEG4MAAsTXwB6YvhHeHyieAx6AAcEXQjDI0rSEDMAXyA)

Comment: Yep, we all probably know this great feature of 3.7, i'll update comment to mark that question is outdated.

Answer (score 9):

There is an issue in the typescript backlog for this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8655. So for now you can't do this.

What you can do, is to use the assertion operator "!". Adding ! after value will assert that the value is neither undefined nor null.  Use this is case where you're absolutely sure it cannot lead to a null or undefined reference.

```
function test() {
     const foo: (FooType|null) = getFoo();
     foo!.bar(); // "!" - asserts that foo is not null nor undefined
}
```

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions

Comment: Thanks. I was almost sure that this was impossible and wanted to write proposal as i wasn't able to find existing one. Thanks for saving me effort to write proposal only to have it marked as dup.

Answer (score 2):

Since `foo` is `Foo | undefined`, its type should be changed to `Foo` somehow.

In the code above, this reasonably can be done with:

```
let foo = getFoo(); // Foo | undefined
foo = assertResultDefined(foo); // Foo
foo.bar();
```

Another option is to use non-null assertion (as another answer suggests):

```
let foo = getFoo();
foo = assertResultDefined(foo);
foo = foo!;
foo.bar();
```

Comment: "type should be changed to Foo somehow" Thanks for reply. Maybe i wasn't explicit enough - i need it for testing code where `Foo | undefined` is part of existing design (maybe good, maybe not, but it's more or less fixed). I already strive to remove all `undefined`s from code but it's not always possible. Nevertheless, hints are cool. +1

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. `Foo | undefined` makes sense, `foo` type just needs to be converted to `Foo` at some point to access object properties freely.

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you:

```js
const foo = (a: number | null) => {
  a = shouldBe(_.isNumber, a)
  a  // TADA! a: number
}

const shouldBe = <T>(fn: (t1) => t1 is T, t) => (fn(t) ? t : throwError(fn, t))

const throwError = (fn:Function, t) => {
  throw new Error(`not valid, ${fn.name} failed on ${t}`)
}
```

where `_.isNumber` has a type guard `x is number`
This can be used with any function with a type guard.

the key is **you must reassign the variable**, so effectively `assert` is an identity function that throws an error on failed type assertion

Comment: I'm using this hack from time to time in various other contexts, but still it's a hack :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner with type safety:

```ts
function assert<T>(value: T | undefined): T {
  if (value === undefined) {
    throw new Error('value is undefined');
  }

  return value;
}
```