# In a TypeScript class, is there a clean way to deal with values that are initially undefined?

Tags: typescript

Imagine a `Connection` class that is instantiated with a password, which it uses to obtain a token from a server. So

- `this.password` is always defined
- `this.token` is undefined until we hear back from the server, but after that it's always defined

```
class Connection {
  password: string
  token?: string

  constructor(password: string) {
    this.password = password
  }

  async connect() {
    // ... connect to server
    this.token = await 'something that we get from the server'
  }

  doStuff() {
    // at this point I know that `this.token` is defined
    const something = someUtilityFunction(this.token)
    // this will fail because TypeScript still thinks this.token might be undefined
  }
}

function someUtilityFunction(token: string) {
  // this function requires `token` to be defined
}

// using the class:
const conn = new Connection('foo')
await conn.connect()
conn.doStuff()
```

I know that I can assert that `this.token` is defined with `!`.

```
class Connection {
  ...
  doStuff() {
    const something = someUtilityFunction(this.token!)
  }
}
```

I could also precede every reference to `this.token` with an [assertion function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362725/typescript-assert-like-type-guard/59017341#59017341):

```
function assert(value: unknown): asserts value {
  if (value === undefined) throw new Error('must be defined');
}

...

class Connection {
  ...
  doStuff() {
    assert(this.token)
    const something = someUtilityFunction(this.token)
  }
}
```

But it feels messy to have to do either of these every single time I refer to `this.token` for the rest of the class's life.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

> But it feels messy to have to do either of these every single time I refer to this.token for the rest of the class's life.

Its not messy.

A property that is optional can essentially always be undefined, and as such needs to be checked whenever you access it.

Solution 1: token is simply not optional

```
class Connection {
  password: string
  token: string

  constructor(password: string) {
    this.password = password;
    this.token = '';
  }
```

If you know that within an anonymous function, `this.token` should be defined, then there's no reason for it to be undefined in the first place.

Solution 2: Assert function

```
function getToken(): string {
  if(this.token) return this.token;
  throw new Error(`Token is not defined`);
}
```

Simply check that `this.token` is defined when using it, you'll only have the `if` in once place.