# Typescript type guard without returning

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I want to have

```
const isNotNull = (object: any) => {
  if (isNull && obj === null) {
    throw new Error('object is null');
  }
}

const obj: null | object = getObject();
isNotNull(obj);
// now I want to enforce that object is no longer null
```

How do I do this? Type guards work only if your function `isNotNull` returns something. I want to infer the type without having my function return anything.

I now want this `someAssertion` to do a type guard, but to be dynamic

Comment: what is ```someAssertion``` ?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59017341/1113002